# String to float error in my python project I am stumped

Tags: python, database, string, spyder

```
# Python code to demonstrate SQL to fetch data.

# importing the module
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import chisquare

# connect withe the myTable database
connection = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\CEP_DB.db")

# cursor object
crsr = connection.cursor()


dog= crsr.execute("Select s, ei, ki FROM cep_db_lite1_vc WHERE s IN ('d')")
ans= crsr.fetchall() 


filtered_data = ans[~np.isnan(ans["ki"])] 


dogData = np.array(filtered_data)
dogData.astype(float)
FdogData= dogData[:, [1,2]]
x, y = FdogData[:,0], FdogData[:,1]

# Reshaping
x, y = x.reshape(-1,1), y.reshape(-1, 1)

# Linear Regression Object 
lin_regression = LinearRegression()

# Fitting linear model to the data
lin_regression.fit(x,y)

# Get slope of fitted line
m = lin_regression.coef_

# Get y-Intercept of the Line
b = lin_regression.intercept_

# Get Predictions for original x values
# you can also get predictions for new data
predictions = lin_regression.predict(x)
chi= chisquare(predictions, y)

# following slope intercept form 
print ("formula: y = {0}x + {1}".format(m, b)) 
print(chi)

# Plot the Original Model (Black) and Predictions (Blue)
plt.scatter(x, y,  color='black')
plt.plot(x, predictions, color='blue',linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

> Error: runfile('C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3/temp.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 22, in 
>       filtered_data = ans[~np.isnan(ans["ki"])]
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I believe I am recieving errors in this section:

```
dog= crsr.execute("Select s, ei, ki FROM cep_db_lite1_vc WHERE s IN ('d')")
ans= crsr.fetchall() 


filtered_data = ans[~np.isnan(ans["ki"])] 


dogData = np.array(filtered_data)
dogData.astype(float)
FdogData= dogData[:, [1,2]]
x, y = FdogData[:,0], FdogData[:,1]
```

How can I fix this script? I have been struggling with this error for weeks to no avail!

Comment: This has nothing to do with type conversion. `ans` is a list, so `ans["ki"]` doesn't make any sense. What do you expect this line of code to do?

Comment: Trying to remove the rows with no entries in column "ki"

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

That means you can't index a list with str, only integers and slices. With that, you can find that in this line:

```
filtered_data = ans[~np.isnan(ans["ki"])]
```

`ans` is a list, and can't be indexed by a string.

Comment: Do I need to convert?

Comment: Well, it's more of what you are trying to do

Comment: Try printing `ans` out. Remember, it's a list.

Comment: Once you print it out you will know what specific value you need